# Python - Correlation Test with Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, data-analysis

I am attempting to analyse the World cup data, I want to make a correlation between the times the games start at and the goals scored. Im hoping this shows that a time may produce more goals.

My dataset is in a csv file and contains the following headings and 1 row of data as an example:

[image]

I am attempting to write the correlation test in python but am having some problems with it.

My question: How do I prove/disprove there is a correlation between times the matches are played at and the amount of goals scored?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

#Read the data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("World Cup 2018.csv")

index2 = df.loc[df['start_time']]
print(index2['home_score'])

Test = numpy.corrcoef(index2.start_time, index2.home_score)[0, 1]
print(Test)
```

Comment: What is this output?

Comment: Also remember when doing analysis that "correlation does not imply causation"

Comment: Yes, I am writing a report and will make note of that, thank you

Comment: Note that correlation quantifies the *linear* relation between two variables but time-of-day is a *circular* quantity. If your hypothesis is correct, games played at 23:00 should be very similar to games played at 01:00. This will lead to a low correlation even if there is a perfect dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Pandas correlation function?

`df.corr()[['start_time']].sort_values('start_time')`

It will give you a set of values for each column in the data frame, and how much it correlates to the start_time:

`home_team   -0.123456
away_team   -0.789012
home_score  -0.890123
away_score  -0.901234`

The higher the score, the more the two values seem correlated.  While it's not a hard and fast rule, a correlation greater than +0.8 is a strong relation

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the quick response. I have tried this and while it looks good I am having trouble with the start_time column

An error is telling me KeyError: "['start_time'] not in index"

Comment: The code may not match your dataframe exactly.  Play around with it a bit, and see if you can get it to work for you, then suggest the edit.  In any case, the corr() function is what you are likely looking for.

Comment: I don't think this will work on teams (which are categorical) or start_time which is probably a datetime or string dtype. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L6501

Comment: The goals are numeric and the start_time is in time format on excel, I will continue to mess around with it, thank you guys

Comment: @OllieinPGH True - I was suggesting a path, and mocking outputs, to quide him in the right direction

Comment: After some messing around I got it sorted, although I did have to change the start time data type. Appreciate the help, thanks very much